# getting complete sql query in jython

Tags: jython

```
result=sqlstring.executeQuery("select distinct table_name,owner from all_tables ")

rs.append(str(i)+' , '+result.getString("table_name")+' , '+result.getString("owner"))
```

If i want to display the query `select * from all_tables`  or `' select count(*) from all_tables'`

how  can i get the output to display . Please suggest thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in another your question: to show query results where you do not know how many columns query returns you must use metadata (best) or iterate and finish when `getString(i)` raises exception.

If you know how many columns is returned, as in `cnt(*)` case you can simply use `rs.getString(1)`:

```
rs = conn.executeQuery("select count(*) from my_table")
while (rs.next()):
   cnt = rs.getString(1)
```

With `cnt(*)` you can use `getInt(1)`, or name column using `AS`:

```
select count(*) as rec_cnt from my_table
```

and get it using `rec_cnt = rs.getInt('rec_cnt')`.

If you use JDBC you should read something about it and get familiar with Java doc like: [RecordSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)